# Getting a TXT record from a domain returned via JSON using javascript

Tags: javascript, json, dns, domain-record

Is there a way to get the TXT record of a domain using javascript with a JSON format? I'm not sure if the browser has something built into this. Or is there a service that gives you a JSON output?

Comment: We can't recommend tools because we don't know your use case.

Comment: Google "javascript dns lookup" and you'll find various solutions.

Comment: I just need it returned as JSON. And no I can't install any local script as I'm not planning on running a server. Mainly looking if I can do this natively in the browser or tap into a public API to query TXT records.

Comment: There is DNS over HTTPS, so query could come from some javascript but the default standard format is still DNS serialization. JSON serialization was standardized last July in RFC8427. There are however various experimental servers doing that. See https://dnsjson.com/ or https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/docs/dns-over-https or https://developers.cloudflare.com/1.1.1.1/dns-over-https/json-format/ or https://dns-api.org/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using **Node.js**: dns.resolveTxt(domain, callback) (http://nodejs.org/api/dns.html)

If you need to do it on the **client side** you can try: https://dns-api.org/TXT/google.com. This approach has it's limitations:

> Clients are limited to 200 lookups per hour, and clients who are abusive or otherwise greedy will be blocked with no notice.
>   If you rely upon this service than you should consider installing your own instance, as this is not a commercial service with any guarantee of availability, reliability, or accuracy.

Comment: I *suspect* they're looking for a client-side, not server-side, solution.

Comment: that is correct. thanks anyways.

Comment: Edited the reply. Take a look to the dns-api.